# Word Count on JavaPairRDD of Hbase Table

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, word-count

There is an example for word count at it's tutorial:

```
JavaRDD<String> textFile = spark.textFile("hdfs://...");
JavaRDD<String> words = textFile.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
  public Iterable<String> call(String s) { return Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")); }
});
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> pairs = words.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
  public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String s) { return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(s, 1); }
});
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = pairs.reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
  public Integer call(Integer a, Integer b) { return a + b; }
});
counts.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://...");
```

However, I have already have a JavaPairRDD as `words` instead of JavaRDD as like:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, WebPage> myRDD
```

and would like to word count on it (which is retrieved from an Hbase database)

So, how can I do word count at that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something pretty similar as well. Assuming that the webPage has a function called `getText()` (and I know it probably doesn't have that exact method) you could write the following:

```
JavaPairRDD<String> words = myRDD.flatMap(
  new FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<String, WebPage> String>() {
    public Iterable<String> call(Tuple2<String, WebPage> sW) {
      return Arrays.asList(sW.getText().split(" "));
  })
```

And from here your existing word count code will function.

Answer (score 0):

```
JavaRDD<String> rdd = myRDD.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<String, WebPage >, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public Iterable<String> call(Tuple2<String, WebPage > tuple2) {
                        //Get web page from the tuple
                        WebPage webPage = tuple2._2();
                        //Invoke appropriate method to extract text
                        String pageText = <get page text>
                        return Arrays.asList(pageText.split(" "));
                    }
                });
```

The code is split into multiple lines, only to explain the usage. You can have it all in single line.